# Curve with no embedding in a toric surface

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, algebraic-curves, convex-polytopes, lattice-polytopes

I am looking for a smooth proper curve $C$ such that there does not exist any closed embedding $C \to S$ where $S$ is a (normal projective) toric surface.

Since $C$ is smooth I believe it suffices to consider smooth projective toric surfaces $S$ since we may always perform a toric resolution of singularities and the strict transform of $C$ will be isomorphic to $C$ since $C$ is smooth.

Using the result on p.25 of Harris Mumford, On the kodaira dimension of the moduli space of curves, I can conclude that a very general curve cannot have any such embedding.

However, I am not able to write down an explicit example. Does anyone know such an example or what sort of obstruction might work to check this in particular examples.

Comment: You might already know this, but there is the notion of a nondegenerate curve which is related but (I think) stronger than your condition, for a definition see Castryck and Voight's article. In that paper they prove that every curve over an algebraically closed field is nondegenerate if its genus is $\leq 4$, so your example will necessarily have genus at least $5$.

Comment: @Jef thanks for the comment. I am familiar with Castryck's work and I think you are correct nondegenerate is a stronger condition it corresponds to an embedding that intersects the toric divisor transversally. There is a related notion of weakly nondegenerate which I do believe corresponds to what I am looking for. However, it appears less is know about when a curve admits a weakly nondegenerate equation.

Comment: Some observations: The divisor $C$ on $S$ corresponds to a lattice polygon, call it $P$. The number of interior lattice points of this polygon is $g$. If the polygon has width $k$ in any lattice direction, then the curve has gonality $\leq k$. Thus, if we are to get a generic curve of genus $g$, the width must be $\geq g/2+1$ in every direction. Also, if $N$ is the number of lattice points and we want to get a generic curve, we must have $N-3 \geq 3g-3$, since the moduli space of curves is $3g-3$ dimensional, and we lose $3$ dimensions rescaling coordinates.

Comment: To be clear, by the width of a lattice polytope $P$, I mean the following: the minimum, over nonzero lattice vectors $v$, of $\max_{p \in P} \langle p,v \rangle - \min_{q \in P} \langle q,v \rangle$.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

A generic curve of genus $5$ is not a hypersurface in a toric surface. This argument is going to use conceptual ideas from Haase and Schicho's paper ["Lattice polygons and the number $2i+7$"](https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0406224v3), plus a bunch of case analysis.

Let's start with generalities about a curve $C$ in a toric surface $S$, other than one of the boundary divisors. The divisor $C$ gives a nef line bundle $\mathcal{O}(C)$ on $S$, which gives a lattice polygon $P$ in $\mathbb{Z}^2$. (See, for example, [Lecture 4 here](https://dacox.people.amherst.edu/lectures/coxcimpa.pdf).) The number of interior lattice points of $P$ will be the genus of $C$.

Let $Q$ be the convex hull of the interior lattice points. So, in our genus $5$ case, $Q$ will be a lattice polytope with $5$ lattice points. Such a polytope either (Case 0) has no interior lattice points (Case 1) has one interior lattice point (Case 2) is a triangle with two interior lattice points or (Case 3) is a line segment of length $4$.

**Case 0** Polytopes with no interior lattice points are trapezoids with vertices of the form $(0,0)$, $(a,0)$, $(0,1)$, $(b,1)$. If we want $5$ lattice points, our options are
$$\mbox{polygon 0a} = \begin{matrix} 
\bullet&&& \\ \bullet&\bullet&\bullet&\bullet \\
\end{matrix} \qquad   
\mbox{polygon 0b} = \begin{matrix} 
\bullet&\bullet& \\ \bullet&\bullet&\bullet \\
\end{matrix}$$

**Case 1** There are $12$ polytopes with $1$ interior lattice point, which you can see in Figure 6 of Haase and Schicho. There are $3$ of these with $5$ lattice points:
$$
\mbox{polygon 1a} =\begin{matrix} &\bullet& \\ \bullet&\bullet&\bullet \\ &\bullet& \\ \end{matrix} \qquad
\mbox{polygon 1b} =\begin{matrix} \bullet&& \\ \bullet&\bullet&\bullet \\ &\bullet& \\ \end{matrix} \qquad
\mbox{polygon 1c} =\begin{matrix} \bullet&& \\ \bullet&\bullet&\bullet \\ \bullet&& \\ \end{matrix}.$$

**Case 2** Wei and Ding, "[Lattice polygons with two interior lattice points](https://doi.org/10.1134/S0001434612050343)", list all lattice polytopes with $2$ interior lattice points. Only one of them has $5$ lattice points:
$$
\mbox{polygon 2} = \begin{matrix} &&\bullet& \\ \bullet&\bullet&\bullet& \\ &&&\bullet \\ \end{matrix}
$$

**Case 3** Finally, here is the line segment:
$$\mbox{polygon 3}=\begin{matrix} \bullet&\bullet&\bullet&\bullet&\bullet \end{matrix}$$

So $Q$ must be one of the $7$ polygons above.

Haase and Schicho show that not every polytope can occur as $Q$. Hasse and Schicho make the following definition: Let $v$ be a vertex of a lattice polytope $Q$, and let $x$ and $y$ be the minimal lattice vectors along the edges incident to $v$. Hasse and Schicho say that $v$ is a "good corner" if $(\vec{x}, \vec{y})$ is $SL_2(\mathbb{Z})$ equivalent to $((1,0), (-1,k))$ for some $k$. Haase and Schicho, Lemma 9, show that $Q$ is always either the empty set, a line segment, or a polytope with good corners. Polygons 0a and 2 do not have good corners, so we can eliminate them now.

We now look at Haase and Schicho, Lemma 8. This lemma says: Let $a_1$, $a_2$ and $b$ be integers with $GCD(a_1, a_2)=1$. Suppose that $a_1 x_1 + a_2 x_2 \leq b$ on $Q$, and that equality occurs at at least two lattice points. Then $a_1 x_1 + a_2 x_2 \leq b+1$ on $P$.

We will apply this result to eliminate polygons 0b and 3. Take $(a_1, a_2) = (0,1)$, so $a_1 x_1 + a_2 x_2$ is the second coordinate. Then Hasse and Schicho's lemma show that the polytope P is contained in a horizontal strip of width $3$ when $Q$ is polygon 0b, and width $2$ in polygon 3. This means that the corresponding curve is trigonal or hyperelliptic, respectively. A generic genus $5$ curve is not trigonal or hyperelliptic.

This leaves cases 1a, 1b and 1c. Haase and Schicho define a polygon they call $Q^{(-1)}$, whose definition I will let you read in their paper, and show that $P \subseteq Q^{(-1)}$. In the figure below, I have redrawn polygons 1a, 1b and 1c with solid dots $\bullet$, and drawn the additional vertices of $Q^{(-1)}$ as hollow circles $\circ$.

$$
\begin{matrix} &&\circ&& \\ &\circ&\bullet&\circ& \\ \circ&\bullet&\bullet&\bullet&\circ \\ &\circ&\bullet&\circ& \\ &&\circ&& \\  \end{matrix} \qquad
\begin{matrix} \circ&&&& \\ \circ&\bullet&\circ&&& \\ \circ&\bullet&\bullet&\bullet&\circ \\ &\circ&\bullet&\circ& \\ &&\circ&& \end{matrix} \qquad
\begin{matrix} \circ&&&& \\ \circ&\bullet&\circ&&& \\ \circ&\bullet&\bullet&\bullet&\circ \\ \circ&\bullet&\circ&&& \\ \circ&&&& \\  \end{matrix}.$$

In each case, there are $13$ lattice points in $Q^{(-1)}$, and thus $\leq 13$ lattice points in $P$. The curve $C$ is the zero locus of a polynomial with this Newton polytope, so it depends on $13$ parameters. But rescaling either of the variables, or rescaling the whole polynomial, does not change the isomorphism class of the curve, so we really only have $10$ parameters. The moduli space of curves of genus $5$ has dimension $12$, so the generic curve of genus $5$ is not a zero locus of a polynomial of any of the above forms. This concludes our case analysis.

---

Writing down an explicit genus $5$ curve which works still seems interesting. We can avoid cases 0b and 3 by just not making our curve hyperelliptic or trigonal. It isn't clear to me what explicit criterion avoids cases 1a, 1b or 1c.

Comment: Hasse should be Haase.

Comment: @ulrich Thanks!